# Android Room Repository Singleton vs Static Methods

Tags: android, repository, android-room, repository-pattern

I feel pretty confused since I can't understand the difference between instantiating a Singleton Repository using a context vs accessing the static Methods directly passing a Context.

**As far as I know, holding a Context reference in any class it's a bad practice due to memory leaks, then why so many people use the first singleton approach instead of using static methods passing the context on demand?**

```
        public class GameRepository {
         private GamesDao gamesDao;
        
         public GameRepository(Context context) {
            gamesDao = RoomDatabase.getInstance(context).getGamesDao();
          }
        
         public Game getGameForIndex(String game) { 
    return gamesDao.getGameById(game); }
        }
```

vs

```
    public class GameRepository {
    
        public static Game getGameForIndex(String game, Context context) {
return RoomDatabase.getInstance(context).getGamesDao().getGameById(game);
        }
    
    }
```

What is better? **Creating and instantiating a Singleton Repository at the constructor or access static methods passing a Context?** What are the advantages/disadvantages or both methods?

Comment: You should post some example code that illustrates what _you_ think a "Singleton" vs "Static Methods" Room Repository looks like. Otherwise your question, which is already soliciting opinions, will garner responses that vary based on each person's own interpretation of each pattern.

Comment: The code you posted, as far as the use of Context is concerned, is identical. Neither one is "holding a Context reference" since in both cases you're just passing the context to the Database getInstance method. That said, you'd probably prefer the first one as it's more testable.